# Background color of button in WPF

Tags: wpf-controls

How to maintain the background color of button even after pressing the Button, right now i am having the style for the button as below

Through Multi triggers using IsPressed property i am changing the background color of button, but i want to preserve the background color even after pressing the button to show that the button was pressed

```
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="Menubtn">
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="35"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="125"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,0,0,0"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="DemiBold"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Calibri"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"></Setter>        
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF0080D4"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border BorderThickness="1" Background="#FF0080D4"  x:Name="GridButton">
                    <Grid>
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"></Condition>
                            <Condition Property="IsPressed" Value="True"></Condition>
                            <Condition Property="IsFocused" Value="True"></Condition>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#6D595C"></Setter>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="GridButton" Value="#EBEBEB"></Setter>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="false"></Condition>
                            <Condition Property="IsPressed" Value="false"></Condition>
                            <Condition Property="IsFocused" Value="false"></Condition>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"></Setter>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="GridButton" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Path=Background}" ></Setter>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>

        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
```

Comment: Sounds like you should be using a ToggleButton, not a Button.

Answer (score 0):

My Button is working now after changing it to the Toggle Button, Thanks to "CodeNaked" Comment